# Reverse looking up a table linked to the profile model linked to the User model

Tags: python, django, request, authentication, django-contrib

I'm uisng `django.contrib.auth` for authentication. The `User` mode has a custom profile model called `Personnel`. `Personnel` is linked to another table called `Company`.

```
class Personnel(models.Model):
    """
    Model for storing the personnel information
    """
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User
    )
    company = models.ForeignKey(
        Company, null=False, verbose_name="Company"
    )

class Company(models.Model):
    """
    Model for storing the company information.
    """
    company_name = models.CharField(
        null=False, max_length=200, verbose_name="Company Name"
    )
```

- Once the user is authenticated. How can i fetch the company for a user? Something like `request.user....`
- In the view, I can access the request but if I need to access the `request` variable in my form and my model, do I need to pass the request variable to the form/model or is there any way to access it? This is because when I'm storing information for a particular `Company`, it should be the company to which that `Personnel` belongs to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to access the company through `request.user.get_profile().company`. See the [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.get_profile).

You cannot access `request` directly in a form, as the form could instantiated somewhere else too, not only in a view where no `request` object exists. You could pass the current user to the form when you initialize it (remember it makes more sense to pass the *user* not the *request*, so you can use it without a request as well).

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user')
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

# in you view
form = MyForm(user=request.user)
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no direct link from User to Company, so you need to do `request.user.personnel.company`.

You'll always need to pass around the `request` explicitly. You can store it inside the form on initialization and access it later:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
  ... fields, meta, etc ...
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
    super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

For Company model instances you can get all Personnel (for future reference in django models names should be singular) by using:

```
company = Company.objects.get(id=some_company_id)
personnel = company.personnel_set.all()
```

If you have a particular Personnel instance:

```
person = request.user.get_profile()
company = person.company
```

For your form.  If your form needs access to the current User then you will need to pass it to it.  You do this by overriding the **init** function on the form

```
class SomeForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
         super(self, SomeForm).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
         self.user = user
```

Comment: Best not to change the signature of form instantiation.